# SQL - Count number of times an ID is in another table without using COUNT()

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/74844b/44

I have one table, with each row being a unique ID. I have another table, with aggregate rows that is sorted by each instance the ID appears in the past.

How can I get a count of that table's rows without using COUNT? I can use JOIN or anything else.

ORDERS

| Date | USERID |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-06 | **3333** |
| 2021-09 | **4444** |

AGG

| Date | User | TransactID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-06 | 3333 | 1234 |
| 2021-03 | 3333 | XXXX |
| 2021-02 | 3333 | XXXX |
| 2021-09 | 4444 | 1238 |
| 2021-05 | 4444 | XXXX |
| 2021-01 | 4444 | XXXX |

RESULT

| TXN_ID | USERID | USERID_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 33333 | 3 |
| 1238 | 44444 | 3 |

Comment: What's wrong with using `count()`?

Comment: I've seen this question before....

Comment: Where does 33333 come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use `OUTER JOIN` with aggregate function instead of subquery.

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT 
    MAX(s.TXN_ID) TXN_ID, a.UserID, COUNT(*) AS USERID_count
FROM
    AGG a 
LEFT JOIN 
    SDP s ON a.USERID = s.USERID
          AND a.DT = s.DT
GROUP BY  
    a.UserID
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/74844b/53/0)**:

```
| TXN_ID | UserID | USERID_count |
|--------|--------|--------------|
|   1234 |  33333 |            3 |
|   1238 |  44444 |            3 |
```

Comment: Hi @ajalberd, I do not understand, your subject is "...without using COUNT()"

Answer (score 0):

You can either use sum like so

```
SUM(x>= 0 and y<= 40) AS count_xx
```

or table rows like so

```
SELECT TABLE_ROWS from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLESWHERE TABLE_NAME = 'foo'
```

or even found_rows

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM fooWHERE bar="value" LIMIT 10;SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I think you already have that info in column count_rank :

```
select SDP.USERID, max(Count_rank)+1
from SDP left join AGG on AGG.UserID = SDP.USERID
group by SDP.USERID
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/74844b/64)

Comment: What if I did not have that column?